# Issue with using Variadic Parameters and C++20 Concept together in Function Template

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, intellisense, c++-concepts

I am writing a function template called average and it takes a variadic parameter.

Environment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 / MSVC Compiler

I have one restraint and two wrapper function:

```
template <typename Type>
concept is_number = std::integral<std::remove_cvref_t<Type>> || std::floating_point<std::remove_cvref_t<Type>>;

template <typename Type>
    requires restraints::is_number<Type>
[[nodiscard]] inline auto averageWrapper(Type&& number)
{
    return number;
}

template <typename Type, class... Args>
    requires restraints::is_number<Type> && (restraints::is_number<Args>&& ...)
[[nodiscard]] inline auto averageWrapper(Type&& head, Args&&... args)
{
    return head + averageWrapper(args...);
}
```

When I do this:

```
template <typename Type, class... Args>
[[nodiscard]] inline auto average(Type&& head, Args&&... args) noexcept
{
    return averageWrapper(head, args...) / (sizeof... (args) + 1); 
}

const std::int64_t num1 { 50 };
const std::int64_t num2 { -60 };
const std::int64_t num3 { 0 };
const double num4 { 12.5 };
const std::int32_t num5 { 10 };

std::cout << average(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5) << std::endl;
```

Intellisense does not produce a squiggly line, and the function works fine.

However, when I add the restraint to the function:

```
template <typename Type, class... Args>
    requires restraints::is_number<Type> && (restraints::is_number<Args>&& ...)
[[nodiscard]] inline auto average(Type&& head, Args&&... args) noexcept
{
    return averageWrapper(head, args...) / (sizeof... (args) + 1);
}

const std::int64_t num1 { 50 };
const std::int64_t num2 { -60 };
const std::int64_t num3 { 0 };
const double num4 { 12.5 };
const std::int32_t num5 { 10 };

// Intellisense warns me that "no instance of the function template matches the argument list"
std::cout << average(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5) << std::endl;
```

Although there is a squiggly line, the code still works! What am I missing here ?

Comment: "*The compiler does not produce a squiggly line*" Compilers don't produce "squiggly lines". Intellisense does that, and C++ Intellisense is not your compiler.

Comment: "_Although there is a squiggly line, the code still works!_": That just means that your IDE's code analysis (e.g. Intellisense) isn't perfect.

Comment: does intellisens use the same compile etc, you compile with?